# How to monitor major compaction of hbase

Tags: java, hbase

I want to monitor major compaction of the hbase.
For each table I would like to know

- when it starts (by hbase or by user)
- when it finished

How can I monitor this?

- via JMX ?
- via UI ?

In general what additional  parameters should I monitor to detect that the major compaction is needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HBase exports lots of metrics through Apache Hadoop's metrics systems.  These metrics are also exposed through jmx.  So [ganglia](http://www.ryangreenhall.com/2010/10/monitoring-hadoop-clusters-using-ganglia/) or [jmx](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) are pretty easy ways to get started on watching the metrics that HBase exports.  Other options include OpenTSDB and propriety entries.

Inside of ganglia or jmx the metric you will want to look at is the hbase.regionserver.compactionQueueSize.  That is the number of compactions that have been scheduled.

The RegionServer UI also includes a copy of some of the metrics, including compactionQueueSize. [image: Here's a screenshot of a 0.94 version.] Later versions of HBase will look better but this gives an example.

Comment: So I can monitor the value hbase.regionserver.compactionQueueSize, and this will define for me the start and end time of compaction? startTime when v > 0 and endTime when v becomes 0 ?

Comment: Nope the hbase.regionserver.compactionQueueSize will just tell you how many are currently queued.  If you need to know exactly how long one single compaction took, the logs in info level will be a good resource.

Comment: Are these logs of the master or should I monitor each region server?

Answer (score 6):

I know the answer is a bit late, but instead of manually looking at the Log-Files you could also give  Hannibal a try. It is a open-source tool that provides History-Graphs for each region. The graphs show when compactions happened and how long they took.

https://github.com/sentric/hannibal/

Answer (score 4):

This is the case for hbase versions 0.96 and 0.98

When a compaction started and Status of HBase Compactions can be gleaned from:
`<hbase.master.ip>:<hbase.master.info.port>/dump`
i.e. `10.4.4.40:60010/dump`

under the section titled

**servers:**

```
    <hostname>,60020,1406845954503: ...<other stuff here>...
    totalCompactingKVs=9121040186, currentCompactedKVs=14351361679,
    compactionProgressPct=1.5734347,...
```

`compactionProgressPct` gives the percentage of compaction completed  that you are currently churning through.

A much friendlier way of viewing compactions is here:

`http://<hbase.regionserver.ip>:<hbase.regionserver.info.port>/rs-status#queueStats`

It will give you stats that look like this:
[image]

Comment: Both of these does not tell whether compaction is major or minor, right? how to know that?

Answer (score 3):

Compaction status can be viewed from Hbase log or Regionservers GUI But if we've huge transaction, It is tough to track compacting region status from log. GUI only shows compacting status on the same node and tedious to view in GUI If we've 'n' regionservers

> Download the utility that collect online compacting region status across Regionservers to a given table. Github [link](https://github.com/karthikpshva/hbaseutility/blob/master/src/main/java/com/alpha/hbase/compaction/StatusUtil.java) to `StatusUtil.java`

Answer (score 0):

We can get compaction status via the JMX.

compactionQueueSize,
compactionSizeNumOps,
compactionSizeAvgTime,
compactionSizeMinTime,
compactionSizeMaxTime,
compactionTimeNumOps,
compactionTimeAvgTime,
compactionTimeMinTime,
compactionTimeMaxTime

Enable JMX metrics as shown at http://hbase.apache.org/metrics.html

You can download the JMX Example [here](https://github.com/karthikpshva/hbaseutility/blob/master/src/main/java/com/alpha/hbase/metrics/JMXRegionServer.java)